# Find data in Excel sheet, add yes to a column H

Tags: excel, vba

The following code searches a sheet called "Data".

If a

Comment: Mmm... your question is not very clear. Which data are you searching? Is entered in to a textbox? Is it like you want to know if the phrase "abc def" exists in a sheet called "Data"?

Answer (score 1):

Your message is not super-well formatted so it is hard to understand how exactly your code is structure.... You should use the `code` function to make it clearer.

Also that looks like very much a homework question to me, so I won't code it for you (I feel that a question on SO should provide its own code.... all you really provide is pseudo-code).

How I would structure my code for this:

I would declare a bolean, say:

```
data_exist: True
```

Then I would loop through my cells. If any of the criteria doesn't match, I would then set my bolean to "False".

You could use a for loop that loops from the 1st cell to the last one in your code. At the beginning of the for loop, insert a if that checks if your bolean == True (because if it equals false there is not point in iterating any further).

Then after that you could have an IF that checks if the bolean == True, and if it does then run your msgbox & everything.

=================== EDIT AFTER-FORMAT================

Thank you sir, much clearer this way. Based on what you provided here's what I would do
I would add another sheet, "check_data". There I would enter all the values that must be present in each rows I want to check. The advantage is that then you can easily edit that values that your check (i.e. they aren't hard-coded), and another user could then edit it without even knowing that VBA is being used for this. Much better approach than hard-coding the answers in your code. I decided to put the data on row 2 of my new sheet, "check_data"

So let's assume that I have this sheet, "check_data". Let's assume I put the data to check (your Txtscan.txt, Source.txt, etc) in such a way that their column number is in exactly the same disposition as the sheet where you are checking the data. This way you could the same variable to iterate over both and simplyfie your code....

```
    Private Sub Cmdnext_Click()
    dim data_exist As Bolean, dim row as integer, dim columns As integer, dim max_row As integer, dim i as integer 'You should declare variable here

 row = 2, columns = 1 max_row = ????????
    'Not sure what your situation for max_row, but you can figure out a way to determine
    'that I am sure. If fixed number it's easy, otherwise there are command to find last used row of a worksheet.


  for i=row to max_row: 'This will iterate over all your rows
    columns = 2, data_exist = True    'Each time you are about to check a new row, you must reset the column number so it increments from 1 to 6 and start by assuming that the data will match

    While data_exist == True And columns < 7  'Check each column in current row ideally again I wouldn't hard-code it but you can just adapt that later

      If Sheets("Data").Cells(row, columns) != Sheets("check_data").Cells(2, columns) Then
        data_exist = False
      Else 
        columns = columns + 1
      End If
    End While

  If data_exist == True Then
    'Put your msgbox or whatever code you want to run here in case data are identical

  Else 
    'Put any code you want to run if the data aren't identical for that row

  End if
  next i

End sub
```

Broadly speaking that should be it. I actually don't have access to MS Excel installed here, so I can't really test the code, its from memory and as you know (or will know soon if you code a lot in VBA) this thing is full of frustrating little quirks & hacks but except for little details that should work. I think its a more flexible structure that what you started with.... Basically the idea is to hard-code the least possible, use function to calculate/find a value. Also adding the answers to check on a separate sheet will work a lot better in the long-run for reasons detailed above...